# Setup 2FA/MFA on Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins, continuous-integration, two-factor, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to find how to setup 2FA/MFA on users who login to Jenkins, with Google Authenticator.

Everything I'm finding is about logins to servers/git/etc, but not for the actual USERS in Jenkins.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the [Google Login plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-login/).

Comment: Nope. What I'm looking for is 2FA with a 6-digit code, using the [Google Authenticator](https://google-authenticator.com/) app.

Comment: Right, that plugin should use 2FA via Google Authenticator if you have it configured on your Google account.

Comment: Without any external 3rd party logins. There's no reason to have to do external logins to be able to implement this 2FA token.

Comment: No, I don't believe there exists a plugin to do Google Authenticator 2FA on local Jenkins accounts.  That seems like a very niche use case to me.  I just assumed you would want to use an external service for authentication - the vast majority of Jenkins admins I've talked to use LDAP, Active Directory, GitHub, Google, or some other service for user authentication rather than local accounts.

Comment: Thanks. But that seems weird to me that this is a niche use case. In my case, Jenkins is hosted on a machine, unlinked from any LDAP/AD network, we have our own Git host, and we don't want to use Google or any 3rd party authentication. All we want is a simple Login (email/password), with an extra step with verification code. Very strange how no one EVER wanted something similar in the past...